# De que forma destacar um item do menu ao clicar Voltar ou Avançar

Tags: javascript, html, css

Isso é possível, sei que estou no caminho, mas antes resolvi ver com a comunidade o que pode ser feito nesse caso, e aí sim tomar o rumo certo.

## Código

```js
function Selecionado(tag){
var item = document.getElementById('menu');

var link = item.getElementsByTagName('a');

for ( var i = 0; i < link.length; i++ ){

 link[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
 link[i].style.color = "";
}
   tag.style.backgroundColor = "#ff0000"; // Cor de fundo do link
   tag.style.color = "#ffffff"; // Cor atual do link
}
```

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; }

button { float: left }

#menu li {
 float: left;
 margin: 5 10px;
 position: relative;
}

a {
  cursor: pointer; padding: 3px; text-decoration: none; color: #111;
}
a.ativo {
  font-weight: bolder;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<button id="menos">&#171 Voltar</button>

<ul id="menu">
   <li><a onclick="Selecionado(this);">1</a></li>
   <li><a onclick="Selecionado(this);">2</a></li>
   <li><a onclick="Selecionado(this);">3</a></li>
   <li><a onclick="Selecionado(this);">4</a></li>
   <li><a onclick="Selecionado(this);">5</a></li>
</ul>

<button id="mais">Avançar &#187</button>
```

> Tem a lógica toda numa só função e o item de menu que ficará em destaque, terá a sua cor de fonte alterada assim como o fundo
>
> Para isso, só preciso ler o id menos/mais para saber que direção tomar.

**Na prática é preciso dar o movimento a esses botões de um modo que fique selecionado um item menu por vez, conforme cada clique**

Vide um exemplo - [Cabeçalho Paginação](http://luis-almeida.github.io/jPages/defaults.html)

## Detalhe

**Preciso de Exemplos numa linguagem simples sem: APIs, DOM4 e ECMAScript 5**

Não são amplamente compatível com diversos navegadores(obsoleto)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes fazer assim, usas a função `muda(num)`, que recebe 1 ou -1.

```js
var id;
function Selecionado(tag,thisid){
  id=thisid;
var item = document.getElementById('menu');

var link = item.getElementsByTagName('a');

for ( var i = 0; i < link.length; i++ ){

 link[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
 link[i].style.color = "";
}
   tag.style.backgroundColor = "#ff0000"; // Cor de fundo do link
   tag.style.color = "#ffffff"; // Cor atual do link
}


function muda(num){
  id+=num;
  var item = document.getElementById('menu');

var link = item.getElementsByTagName('a');

for ( var i = 0; i < link.length; i++ ){

 link[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
 link[i].style.color = "";
}
  
  document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = "#ff0000"; // Cor de fundo do link
  document.getElementById(id).style.color = "#ffffff"; // Cor atual do link
}
```

```html
<button id="menos" onclick="muda(-1);">&#171 Voltar</button>

<ul id="menu">
   <li><a onclick="Selecionado(this,1);" id="1">1</a></li>
   <li><a onclick="Selecionado(this,2);" id="2">2</a></li>
   <li><a onclick="Selecionado(this,3);" id="3">3</a></li>
   <li><a onclick="Selecionado(this,4);" id="4">4</a></li>
   <li><a onclick="Selecionado(this,5);" id="5">5</a></li>
</ul>

<button id="mais" onclick="muda(1);">Avançar &#187</button>
```